# Parshape has no effect inside group

Tags: tex-core, grouping, parshape

In the MWE below the `\parshape` command behaves as expected. However if you add grouping (by uncommenting the two lines marked with a `(*)`) then it seems to have no effect! How do I make it behave like it does in the ungrouped setting when inside a group?  (By the way, the reason I want a group is that I want to use commands like `\small` and have it reset automatically when I'm done.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

%{ % (*)
\def\wide{0em \linewidth}
\def\narrow{5em \dimexpr\linewidth-5em}

\parshape3 \wide\narrow\wide
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Donec cursus turpis et leo mollis, ac efficitur nulla vehicula. 
Ut vel dolor sit amet libero tempus consequat. 
Aliquam non auctor leo. 
Ut auctor lacinia nisi. 
Duis id venenatis quam, ut suscipit libero. 
Curabitur nisi enim, vehicula et massa quis, pharetra tincidunt nisi. 
Morbi luctus nibh urna, suscipit rhoncus mi sodales quis.
%} % (*)

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need a `\par` before the closing `}` in the group.

Comment: @AlanMunn is my answer too bad to keep it? Do you suggest to delete? Edit: Deleted... I opened a second group instead of closing the old...

Comment: @koleygr Yes.  Commands like `\parshape`, `\centering` and font switches need to see the end of a paragraph, so you need a `\par` to end them.

Comment: The paragraph ended outside the group. You don't have to add `\par` inside the group; you can also just add a blank line.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I agree, although in this case, the `\par` makes things clearer, I think.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Various things that affect the typesetting of a paragraph, such as `\parshape` (but also other things like `\centering`, `\baselineskip`, `\leftskip`) only come into effect at the end of a paragraph. This means that if a paragraph is set inside a group, you must explicitly end the paragraph inside the group with a `\par` or a blank line.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

{ % (*)
\def\wide{0em \linewidth}
\def\narrow{5em \dimexpr\linewidth-5em}

\parshape3 \wide\narrow\wide
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Donec cursus turpis et leo mollis, ac efficitur nulla vehicula. 
Ut vel dolor sit amet libero tempus consequat. 
Aliquam non auctor leo. 
Ut auctor lacinia nisi. 
Duis id venenatis quam, ut suscipit libero. 
Curabitur nisi enim, vehicula et massa quis, pharetra tincidunt nisi. 
Morbi luctus nibh urna, suscipit rhoncus mi sodales quis.
\par
} % (*)

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]